# MODX snippet Login через Ajax

Tags: ajax, modx

Как в modx пустить регистрацию и авторизацию через Ajax, есть необходимость всё в модалку засунуть. Всё перерыл ничего конкретного не нашел. Через AjaxForm не работает.